# Android keyboard for non support language

Tags: android, fonts, android-virtual-keyboard

I am developing a keyboard for a new language that is not supported by android. I have design fonts that are to be used. How can I use the font to design keyboard in Andriod?

Comment: as far as I know, keyboard consists of the buttons. So you apply a custom font to it same way as for a regular button.

Comment: thanks @VladMatvienko. I was thinking of similar idea but I couldn't include the font to display the characters and stream them on the input text field

Comment: that's another thing. The application, that is using your keyboard should support your characters in it's font too

Comment: for example in andriod message, by having my font attached to keyboard will the characters be supported?

Comment: no, since *android message* is another application. *another application* should support those characters too.